# cannot read property 'get' of undefined in angular 2

Tags: angular

in main.ts

```
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent,[HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

in employee.service.ts

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import {Employee} from '../classes/employee';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService{
  constructor(private http: Http){
      this.http = http;
  }
}
```

i see http as undefined even after constructor is called.

Any help please...........

Comment: I have started learning angular2. From couple of days, I have spend time on this issue. Any help would be great

Comment: I didn't see anything wrong in your code, yet you haven't posted enough details in order we could help. For example, errors in the console, the part of the code where you are injecting EmployeeService.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I forgot **providers: [EmployeeService]** in the xyz.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working http://plnkr.co/edit/ymvo2AmnkpyWvcnJLMKC?p=preview

First, mark your service with @Injectable() so Angular runtime knows, that it should be handeled by DI.

```
@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService{
  constructor(private http: Http){
      this.http = http;
  }
}
```

Second, make sure, that you dont forget to bootstrap *HTTP_PROVIDERS* to your app:

```
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';

...

bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, EmployeeService]);
```

See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#injectable

Comment: But I don't see the @Injectable() on your EmployeeService

Comment: I didn't add in the post. But it was in my code. Now added in the post too :) ...

Comment: I have added working plunker, if you check the console, you can clearly see, that Http is valid object. Didnt you forget to add providers array to your Component?

Comment: Thanks a ton Petr... I forgot provider in the blabla.component.ts
Great support from you

Comment: Glad that it works now..so will you accept my answer?